# Why does $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{8}} \frac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{8})^t}$ equal, $(2 \times 8) \frac{1^t}{2^t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1}{8}} \dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{8})^t}$

=

$(2 \times 8) \dfrac{1^t}{2^t}$

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to know these:

- $\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{8}}=8.$
- $\sqrt[3]{8}=8^{\dfrac{1}{3}}=2$, because $2^3=8$.
- $1^t=1$.

Replace now, to get:

$$(2\times 8)\dfrac{1^t}{2^t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac2{\frac18}\frac1{(\sqrt[3]8)^t}=16\frac1{2^t}\;\ldots$$

after using the rule

$$\frac{\frac ab}{\frac cd}=\frac ab\cdot\frac dc=\frac{ad}{bc}$$